# How can I implement html input form without backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to implement a contact form in my site, similar to this, but simpler. (I only need email and content inputs)
http://www.squarespace.com/contact/

The problem is that I have no backend support. (just some static html pages)

Question: How can I implement my contact form in static html pages?

Possible solution:
I know there are 3rd party tools that allow you to embed their js in your page and they will persist your data on their server. I once came across one but forget its name... Could you guys suggest one, or provide better solution?

Comment: why can't you use a back end scripting language with a database?

Comment: Are you hosting your website on SquareSpace.com?

Comment: My site is hosted on a server like github pages. Anyway, only static html are allowed

Comment: Check out http://www.wufoo.com

Comment: Can you use an iframe? Cross-domain ajax? `mailto` link? How about just link to another site under your control?

Comment: Google Forms to a Google Spreadsheet. Not professional enough?

Comment: @Wint check out my answer! may that plugin help you!

Comment: Google forms sounds like a plausible way to achieve what you want...

Comment: @WesleyMurch, yes I can use iframe. I can't use mailto because it opens an email client app. it is an option to embed a page from another domain, I will think about it, thanks.

Comment: @Wint Some browsers allow you to use `mailto` as a form's `action`, it will email the form data to you without using the user's email client. It's a little weird but it might be worth looking at.

Comment: You can setup a micro aws server for free for 1 year right now, you could easily stand up a server to accept requests and mail it to you. http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: you can use a service like [formsubmit.co](https://formsubmit.co) to submit form without back-end

Comment: Try ActionForms.io !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the contents of a form emailed to you, the form needs to be submitted to a server that can run a processing script that will either store the form data in a database or email the form data to your email address.

You can either get your own hosting account or pay a 3rd party service to process your form for you.

Either way, you will probably need to pay for a hosting account or a hosted solution.

If you search online for: "hosted web form solutions" you will see dozens of possible solutions.

You need to research the options.

If you need a form mail script, I have often used the following:

http://www.tectite.com/

Tectite.com also offers a hosted form solution.

Comment: Your answer is informative, thanks

Comment: I was looking for the same solution and I builth http://www.formester.com it has the goodness of the costliest form backend at an affordable price. I hope it helps.

Comment: checkout this link http://rohitvinay.com/how-to-store-contact-form-data-without-backend/

Comment: there are several services like [formsubmit.co](https://formsubmit.co) to submit form without back-end

Answer (score 2):

There are many alternatives, but you should [try google forms](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/87809?hl=en) first. You can [embed their forms](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90569?hl=en) within an IFRAME but they will take the users out of your site after the form has been submitted. If you don´t like that, or if you want to control the styles for the form, [follow these steps](http://morning.am/tutorials/how-to-style-google-forms/). Google forms also support mailing you whenever a new form is sent (you can set that up in the associated spreadsheet).

Other alternatives are http://www.jotform.com/ or http://www.wufoo.com/

Basically, these solutions will allow you to insert pure HTML and sometimes JavaScript into your site and the inserted script or HTML will load the the form from the external system or simply post the form to the external system without any back-end on your site.

Comment: Thanks jacmkno, you have decent answer, but I have adopted Marc's suggestion by using tectite

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't do it using JavaScript or jQuery alone. You'd need a server-side handler to connect with the SMTP server to actually send the mail for your form. There are some pretty simple PHP scripts that can send mail, and you can use

[jQuery.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post)

To send the data